# How do I call a variable to a method in Ruby (NOT Rails)

Tags: ruby, database, crud

```
people = {}

def add

    puts "Enter the name of the person you would like to add in the database."
    name = gets.chomp.to_s

    if people[name].nil?

        puts "What is #{name}'s age?"
        age = gets.chomp.to_i

        people[name] = age.to_i
end

puts "Would you like to add?"
choice = gets.chomp

if choice == "yes"
      add
end

end
```

So Ive got people outside my method "add", I get an error "undefined local variable or method `people' for main: Object (NameError)"

I am getting an error ass soon as people[name].nil? line comes.

I have to create a database, I have more methods like update and delete, how do I use / call "people" inside these methods?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you indent your code correctly. It'll save your future self a lot of anguish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Global variables should be prefixed by `$` in Ruby, so you need `$people` in place of `people`. Alternatively, you can pass in `people` to your `add` function.

As pointed out by theTinMan, the correct solution is to refactor your code in a way to avoid the use of global variables in the first place, by passing in the `people` to your function:

```
def add(people)
    ...
```

Comment: Just tried that, still getting the same exact error.

Comment: `add': undefined local variable or method `people' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: Did you replace every instance of `people` with `$people`?

Comment: Using global variables isn't the solution to the problem, it's only a bandaid. Understand how variable scoping works instead. Using a global should be very, very, rare and only done when you understand why you shouldn't use them and how it's safe to use them.

Comment: @theTinMan yes, you are correct, and I've edited my answer to mention this. But global variables are a part of the language and deserve to be understood and used correctly too.